# How to write on the server data edited by the client

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I want a Select Box where I can Filter the Data from the Database (with Ajax - no site reload). For example: Order the data by ID or Order the data by name
Thats working fine and now when I get that data I want also that I can edit the data with Inputs and save it (also trough ajax) but I dont know how. I know how to save data with ajax but not when the data is a response from another ajax.

Code: (Its not well formatted here, that's why pastebin: http://pastebin.com/7mgi6VMc)

Index:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <p id="result">Erfolgreich gespeichert!</p>
    <br>
    <div class="filter">
        <form>
            Anzeige: 
            <select class="selectFilter" onchange="filterFunction(this.value)">
                <option value="id_back">ID - Aufwärts</option>
                <option value="id_up">ID - Abwärts</option>
            </select>
        </form>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div id="resultCatalogue">
        <b>Bitte wähle die gewünschte Anzeige ...</b>
    </div>
</div>
```

getData.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//fonts.googleapis.com/css?    family=Open+Sans" />
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>

<script>
$("#save").on("submit", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./save.php",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            if($('#result').css('display') == 'none') {
                document.getElementById('result').style.display = 'block'
            } else {
                document.getElementById('result').style.display = 'none'
                setTimeout(function() {
            document.getElementById('result').style.display =     'block'
                }, 100);                
            }   
        },
    });
 });
</script>

</head>
<body>

<?php
$type = intval($_GET['type']);

if($type == "id_up") 
{
echo '
        <table class="tableCatalogue">
    <tr>
        <th class="th" width="5%">ID</th>
        <th class="th" width="5%">Unter-ID</th>
        <th class="th" width="15%">Titel</th>
        <th class="th" width="5%">Iceron</th>
        <th class="th" width="10%">Sichtbar</th>
        <th class="th" width="10%">Aktiv</th>
        <th class="th" width="5%">Min. Rank</th>
        <th class="th" width="5%">VIP</th>
        <th class="th" width="5%">Reihen Nummer</th>
        <th class="th" width="10%">Layout</th>
    </tr>
    <form method="post" id="save">
    ';

    $index = 0;
    $getCataloguePages = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM catalog_pages");
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($getCataloguePages))
    {
        $id = $row['id'];
        $parent_id = $row['parent_id'];
        $caption = $row['caption'];
        $icon_image = $row['icon_image'];
        $visible = $row['visible'];
        $enabled = $row['enabled'];
        $min_rank = $row['min_rank'];
        $min_vip = $row['min_vip'];
        $order_num = $row['order_num'];
        $page_layout = $row['page_layout'];

        $i++;
        if(IsEven($i)){
            $even = "Even";
        } else {
            $even = "Odd";
        }
    echo '
    <tr>
        <td class="td'.$even.'" width="5%"><input placeholder="ID" class="inputTable" name="id[]" value="'.$id.'"></td>
        <td class="td<?php echo $even; ?>" width="5%"><input placeholder="Unter-ID" class="inputTable" name="parent_id[]" value="'.$parent_id.'"></td>
        <td class="td<?php echo $even; ?>" width="15%"><input placeholder="Titel" class="inputTable" name="caption[]" value="'.$caption.'"></td>
        <td class="td<?php echo $even; ?>" width="5%"><input placeholder="Icon" class="inputTable" name="icon_image[]" value="'.$icon_image.'"></td>
        <td class="td<?php echo $even; ?>" width="5%"><select placeholder="Sichtbar" class="selectTable" name="visible[]"><option value="1">Sichtbar</option><option value="0">Nicht sichtbar</option></select></td>
        <td class="td<?php echo $even; ?>" width="5%"><select placeholder="Aktiviert" class="selectTable" name="enabled[]"><option value="1">Aktiv</option><option value="0">Nicht aktiv</option></select></td>
        <td class="td<?php echo $even; ?>" width="5%"><select placeholder="Mindest Rank" class="selectTable" name="min_rank[]"><option>1</option></select></td>
        <td class="td<?php echo $even; ?>" width="5%"><select placeholder="VIP" class="selectTable" name="min_vip[]"><option value="1">Nur VIP</option><option value="0">Alle</option></select></td>
        <td class="td<?php echo $even; ?>" width="5%"><input placeholder="Reihen Nummer" class="inputTable" name="order_num[]" value="'.$order_num.'"></td>
        <td class="td<?php echo $even; ?>" width="10%"><input placeholder="Layout" class="inputTable" name="page_layout[]" value="'.$page_layout.'"></td>
    </tr>
    ';
    $index++;
    } 
    echo '
    <input class="save" type="submit" name="save" value="Speichern">
    <br><br>
    </form>
</table>
';

?>
<script>
$("#save").on("submit", function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./save.php",
        data: $(this).serialize(),
        success: function(data) {
            if($('#result').css('display') == 'none') {
                document.getElementById('result').style.display = 'block'
            } else {
                document.getElementById('result').style.display = 'none'
                setTimeout(function() {
                    document.getElementById('result').style.display = 'block'
                }, 100);                
            }   
        },
    });
});
</script><?php
}

?>
```

save.php:

```
$size = count($_POST['id']); 
$i = 0; 
while ($i < $size) 
{
    $id = $_POST['id'][$i];         
    $query = "UPDATE catalog_pages SET id = '".$id."' LIMIT 1"; 
    mysql_query($query) or die ("Error in query: $query"); 
    ++$i; 
}
```

Like I said, everything is included. Database Connection, all fine.
It is also showing me the Response with the Select but then I want to Update that data - also with ajax.

Where do I have do place the Ajax Code? How can I do that?

Comment: Please update the question with a short but descriptive **title** that describes your problem as well as clarify your question. For more information, see [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean here - you want to populate a dropdown box from AJAX source data, but then you also want a separate set of input boxes that load data back onto your server via ajax?  Is that correct? Or do you want the initial dropdown box to populate with something, but have that something be editable?

Comment: I want a dropdown box where I can choose if the mysql data should filtered by id or name or something like that. Then, the data should be displayed in a table (the data is a whole mysql table). And then There should be a big table with inputs where I can edit and save the data. everything with ajax. The dropdown and filtering is working fine but I dont know how to make it, that I can edit the data which is displayed.

Comment: Take a look at intval function, the return value is an int, and then you are trying to compare it to a string, that will never be true. Start debugging from there